# How to tell Visual Studio that Bootstrap files are updated?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am trying to install Bootstrap Datetimepicker on a PC which is not connected to the Internet.

I have the Bootstrap Datetimepicker nupkg files. I added the folder of the files as a Package Source. When I try to install the package, I get the error:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies. 'bootstrap 3.0.0' is not compatible with 'Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS 4.17.45 constraint: bootstrap (>= 3.3.0)'
```

I already copied all CSS and JS files of Bootstrap 3.3.7 to the relevant folders in my project. How do I tell Visual Studio that they have been updated?

Comment: This is the most annoying error I've ever seen. Even occurs when you try to update non-bootstrap packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I tell Visual Studio that they have been updated?

You need **update the package bootstrap to 3.3.0 or later**.

[image]

You want to update package `Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker` to `4.17.45`, which has a Dependencies limitation: `bootstrap (>=3.3.0)`. So you need update the package bootstrap.

[image]

> I already copied all CSS and JS files of Bootstrap 3.3.7 to the relevant folders in my project

**NuGet manager the packages as a whole** will not modify the internal data, so even you have already copied all CSS and JS files of Bootstrap 3.3.7, nuget still manager the previous package `Bootstrap 3.0.0`. To resolve this issue, just update the package Bootstrap to 3.3.0 or later.